# Ionic: Camera asks confirmation after every picture / take multiple shots

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-camera, ngcordova

**Is it possible to disable those annoying "retry" and "ok" buttons from top of the display?** I can also customize ngCordova plugin if you guide me to a correct direction.

What I want to do is to take multiple shots easily. Now it takes time, because someone have invented that one should confirm if picture is good enough. So **another questions is** what is suggested way to take multiple pictures and then confirm all of them.

Both of the following lines give same result:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture()
```

or

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture()
```

[image: Annoying retry and ok -buttons]

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I want to hide this 2 buttons..

Comment: Hi! Any update on this? i want to skip this confirmation step

Comment: I found that adding intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.quickCapture", true); should work in the plugin but its not working for me, did you find anything??

Comment: @SaurabhUdaniya not yet, i need to try that option also. Thanks!

Comment: Do we have any solution for this?

Comment: @anoop havent tried yet :)

Comment: Still no solution in 2020 on Android?

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same requirement for one of my apps.

Here you go

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview

This plugin exposes a method takePicture() which you will be able to call continuously and get all the pictures into an array or something that you wish.

Go through the plugin documentation for more details on implementation.

For your reference, here is a sample app made with cordova-plugin-camera-preview

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview-sample-app

To answer your question, the best way of allowing the users to confirm the pictures, I would suggest you that first let user capture as many pictures they want, then you display them in a gallery view, where they can tap on a picture - they will see two options 1.Replace photo 2.Delete photo.

This way, users will have a good user experience.